# Can there exists a 6 digit number whose pairwise sum of digits is unique?

Tags: permutations, combinations

eg- such a 5 digit number is 84210

Pair wise digits sum are 12(8+4), 10(8+2),9(8+1),8(8+0),6(4+2),5(4+1),4(4+0),3(2+1),2(2+0),1(1+0).

What I tried->
taking 2 digits from a 6 digit number is 6C2 = (6*5)/2=15
Now our pairwise sum ranges from 1(1+0) to 17(9+8). So there are 17 unique sum  possible and we need only 15. So theoretically it should be possible. But is it possible practically? If yes, give one such number?

Comment: First observation: all digits in such a number must be unique.  If there was a repeated digit, say for example $\overline{aabcde}$ then we would have the sum $a+b$ appearing twice, once for using the first $a$ and the $b$ and again for using the second $a$ and the $b$.

Comment: @Bram28:  because we are using only pairwise sums, the $8$ could be replaced by $7$, spoiling the binary.

Comment: @Bram28 $74210$ has the same property, pairwise sums $11,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1$ respectively.  Pointing out that the digits that happened to appear in his example are powers of two is not entirely relevant here.

Comment: $95321$ works as well for five digits.

Comment: @RossMillikan You're right .. .!

Comment: It is worth noting that whichever digit we remove from a six digit number, we are left with a five digit example.

Comment: Since all numbers must be unique, and the property being searched for doesn't make any reference to the digits actual location in the number, we may assume without loss of generality that our number has its digits appearing in decreasing order.  Consider the distance between each pair of adjacent digits.  If such a distance repeats and there is no overlap between the pairs, e.g. if our number is $\overline{abcdef}$ and the distance between $a$ and $b$ is the same as the distance between $c$ and $d$ then we would have $a+d=b+c$.  See if you can argue why a distance must repeat.

Comment: If the highest digit is $8$ and you need $15$ sums you need $7$ to get $8+7=15$ and you also need $0+1=1$. But then you have $8+0=7+1=8$.

The highest digit is therefore $9$. If the lowest digit is greater than $0$ you can deduct $1$ from each digit, and $2$ from each sum, retaining the disjoint sums property. So the lowest digit has to be $0$. This is serious constraint - Ross M has got a full solution - so I'll just leave this as a note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible.  If you use $0$ and $1$, you can't use any neighboring digits and the only choice is $013579$ which fails to $1+9=3+7$.  If you use $0$ and not $1$ or $2$ you can't -get $1,2,3$ and there aren't enough possibilities.  If you use $0$ and $2$ but not $1$ you can't get $1$ or $3$ and have to use all the others, but means you need $9$ and $8$ to get $17$, you need $7$ to get $16$ and $0+9=7+2$.  If you don't use $0$ you can't get $1$ or $2$, so need $8,9$ to get $17$ and $1,2$ to get $3$, but $1+9=2+8$

Comment: Wow. Nicely explained